# Issue Deploying .NET Core WebAPI Project

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Hosting company says they have .Net Core 2.2.1 Runtime installed.

I tried to publish  project using Framework Dependent Deployment and got error 500. More specifically:

```
    It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      C:\Program Files\dotnet\
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
      https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
  - The following versions are installed:
      2.1.10 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
```

Contacted hosting company, and they said they don't have Microsoft.AspNetCore.App installed, only Microsoft.NetCore.App. Which I honestly don't really understand.

My question is... I have a WebAPI project, simple thing. How can I deploy to this server?? If they don't have AspNetCore installed, can I provide it? Like most people, I'm new to core... just want to publish this project, it seems like an impossible task.

I did try Self-Contained deployment (they said they don't support it), but got the 500 error.

Here's what they have installed:

```
==============================
.NET Core SDKs installed:
No SDKs were found.

.NET Core runtimes installed:
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
==============================
```

Ideas anyone? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, different .net core farmwork version may have different feature. That means you may need doing some changes for your web api source codes. The common way to solve this issue is modifying your web api application version to 2.2.1 in your develop environment and make sure there is no error and re-publish the application to the remote server.

Comment: My best advice is to get a real host. Shared hosting is insanity unless you're running a little Wordpress blog no one visits. You can get a $5/mo VPS from many places, and then you control the whole shebang. If you don't have the right runtime, you install the right runtime. No limitations.